# table exists on 'show tables' - can't query

Tags: mysql

Anybody know why this his happening?

```
 mysql> show tables;

 +-------------------+
 | Tables_in_photos  |
 +-------------------+
 | captions_images   |
 | image_meta        |
 | mentions_images   |
 | tags_images       |
 | words             |
 +-------------------+
 5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 mysql> select * from captions_images;
 ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'ig_call.captions_images' doesn't exist
 mysql>
```

I tried repairing the table to no avail. What could help fix it?

Comment: Is this under Linux/Unix? Which engine are you using (MyISAM, InnoDB)? What does the table/tablespace look like in the datadir? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759170/mysql-table-doesnt-exist-but-it-does-or-it-should

Comment: Issue the two commands "show schemas;" and "select database();" and show us the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the question again. You ran

```
mysql> show tables;
```

What does the output header say ?

```
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_photos  |
+-------------------+
```

That means you were standing in the `photos` database.

If you had run

```
SELECT database();
```

or

```
SELECT schema();
```

It would have echoed `photos`.

Now, look at the error message

```
mysql> select * from captions_images;
 ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'ig_call.captions_images' doesn't exist
```

Since you were standing in the `ig_call` database and you issued `select * from captions_images;`, mysql assumed you want to select from `captions_images` tables in the `ig_call` database.

Try the following

```
select * from photos.captions_images limit 10;
```

If you get the same kind of message, then you have corrupt table issues in terms of the InnoDB data dictionary. If you get data, then you were simply in the wrong place at the wrong time. In your case, you were in the wrong database at the wrong time.